# Ping a host remoto es muy lento con PHP

Tags: php, web, php7, apache

tengo un problema con mi codigo php a la hora de la ejecución el rendimiento es muy pobre. Ejemplo: Si hago ping a una unica direccion ip el proceso tarda 1ms, al agregar mas direcciones en mi array el tiempo escala de una manera exagerada (15 segundos para hacer ping a 3 direcciones).
Quizas sea algo de apache, pero la verdad lo ignoro. Muchas gracias!

```
<?php

$ip= array("192.168.60.250","192.168.45.250","192.168.16.250","192.168.15.250","192.168.15.62" );



for ($i=0; $i < count($ip); $i++) { 

        $ping= exec("ping -n 1 $ip[$i]",$output,$status);
        $statusVec[$i]=$status;
        echo $statusVec[$i];
        echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: los quite y no cambió nada :D

Comment: Entonces debes leer acá la primera respuesta y ver si funciona. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php Al parecer, con exec, estás esperando que cmd termine antes de obtener las respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, intentaré con eso!

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el retardo se produzca por la red en vez de por el código , ¿puedes lanzar una prueba lanzando multiples pings a tu localhost?

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).